# copy all css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how can copy all css property and add to another element with JQuery?

```
<div class="copy"></div>
<div class="past"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.copy{

    width:50px; height:50px;
    background-color:pink;
    border: 1px solid red;

}
```

Comment: $('div').addClass('copy')

Comment: yes, it's work well... but I want copy css property and to another element

Comment: Couldn't you just change `.copy{...` to `.copy, .past {...`?

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem** being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work**, and the expected results.

Comment: You could use this : http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1817/ but the real solution would probably be to fix your program so that you don't need to copy all CSS properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

Comment: I don't even know what you mean by "copy css property", since apparently neither adding `.past` to the css selector or adding `copy` to the target element will do. A little context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.past').addClass($('.copy')
```

but if you want to do it with another way

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/QrJVU/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".copy").click(function(){
        var array = ['color','width','height', 'background-color', 'border'];
        var $this = $(this);
        $.each( array , function(item, value) {
            $(".past").css(value, $this.css(value));
        });
    });
});
```

another way or you can say the `best way`

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/V5pEY/)

[**Source**](http://upshots.org/javascript/jquery-copy-style-copycss)

```
(function($){
    $.fn.getStyleObject = function(){
        var dom = this.get(0);
        var style;
        var returns = {};
        if(window.getComputedStyle){
            var camelize = function(a,b){
                return b.toUpperCase();
            };
            style = window.getComputedStyle(dom, null);
            for(var i = 0, l = style.length; i < l; i++){
                var prop = style[i];
                var camel = prop.replace(/\-([a-z])/g, camelize);
                var val = style.getPropertyValue(prop);
                returns[camel] = val;
            };
            return returns;
        };
        if(style = dom.currentStyle){
            for(var prop in style){
                returns[prop] = style[prop];
            };
            return returns;
        };
        return this.css();
    }
})(jQuery);
$.fn.copyCSS = function(source){
  var styles = $(source).getStyleObject();
  this.css(styles);
}
$('.past').copyCSS('div.copy');
```

Comment: there is no any way that value of `var array` are automatically identified?

Comment: check the new update code

Answer (score 1):

How about just changing your CSS?

```
.copy, .past {
    width:50px; height:50px;
    background-color:pink;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I want copy css property... and to to another element with jquery

Answer (score 1):

just use `$('.past').addClass('copy');`

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UYMxa/15/)

Comment: I want copy css property... and to to another element with jquery

Comment: this is what addClass does...it will simply copy all your css and apply it to your selector...what is it that you dont understand in this..this is the simplest of simplest codess...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a bit of JavaScript. Here's a "pure" JavaScript solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/hRtRu/

```
function getCamel(str) {
    return str.replace(/^(-\w)/, function(m) {
        return m.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }).replace(/(-\w)/g, function(m) {
        return m.substring(1).toUpperCase();
    });
}
function getAllStyles(elm) {
    var result = {};
    if(window.getComputedStyle) {
        var styles = window.getComputedStyle(elm, null);
        for(var i=0; i<styles.length; i++) {
            var val = styles.getPropertyValue(styles[i]);
            var key = getCamel(styles[i]);
            if(val != "")
                result[key] = val;
        }
    } else if(elm.style) {
        for(var i=0; i<elm.style.length; i++) {
            var key = getCamel(elm.style[i]);
            var val = elm.style[key];
            if(val != "")
                result[key] = val;
        }
    }    
    return result;
}
function copyAllStyles(srcElm, dstElm) {
    var styles = getAllStyles(srcElm);
    for(var key in styles)
        if(styles.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            dstElm.style[key] = styles[key];
            if(key == "backgroundColor")
            console.log(key, styles[key], dstElm.style.backgroundColor);
        }
}

var src = document.getElementById("demo");
var dst = document.getElementById("demo2");
window.setTimeout(function(){
    copyAllStyles(src, dst);
}, 2000);
```